# AWS Lambda different IP address for each Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to have each Lambda access the internet from a different IP address? In my testing, it appears the each time a Lambda is invoked it uses the same IP address to access our servers.

Our Lambdas do not have VPC access and are not NAT'd. I would think we would get different IP addresses with this setup but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I am wondering if it's possible that our because our volume is low we just always end up using the same container hence the same IP address? If so is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by requiring each lambda have a unique IP? The answer to your question is no, you cannot mangage how AWS executes your Lambda function.

Comment: I would imagine the lower the volume, the less likelihood you would get to reuse the same container. Only beneficial for high volume to reuse containers

Comment: Are you trying to use Lambda to scrape information from websites that specifically prohibit scraping, so you are trying to disguise your usage by using different IP addresses? If so, please examine the Terms and Conditions of websites and stop trying to counter them.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We have a client with an application that takes websites and reformats them for viewing for people with accessibility limitations. Part of this process involves sending data from the application to a server for processing. The issue comes when a link is shared and several people access the same URL. We are thinking about several ways to solve this using caching or issuing the requests app side. If we could make the lambda thing work it's much less work and can be immediately deployed without application development or adding additional infrastructure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am wondering if it's possible that our because our volume is low we just always end up using the same container hence the same IP address?

Yes, that is exactly the reason.  A container is only spawned if no containers are already available.  After a few *minutes* of no further demand, excess/unneeded containers are destroyed.

> If so is there any way to prevent this?

No, this behavior is by design.

Answer (score 1):

When you redeploy the lambda it seems to use a new container. So you can automate this deploy process using awscli to get a new ip on command.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to redeploy the code each time. I use boto3's [update_function_code](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_code).

Add the following code anywhere in the function, it will deploy it for further calls. Therefore, the next Lambda will run from a different IP address.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('lambda')

response = client.update_function_code(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda...',
    S3Bucket='bucket-name',
    S3Key='function.zip',
    Publish=True
)
```

Then export the function to a zip file, rename it as "function.zip" and upload it to an S3 bucket that matches the S3Bucket variable.

Note: It takes a few seconds to deploy the code. I'd suggest you use SQS with a delay time to manage the requests.