# npm:youtube-dl and Lamda HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, youtube, youtube-dl

I am running an npm package: youtube-dl through a Lambda function as I want to create an online convertor.

I have suddenly started to run into the following error message:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Command failed: /var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl --dump-json --format=best[ext=mp4] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfTbHITdhEI\nERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.\n",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": ["ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.", "", "ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)", "emitTwo (events.js:126:13)", "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)", "maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)", "Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)"]
}
```

Edit: I have run this a few times when I was testing the other day, but today I only ran it once.

I think that the IP address used by my Lambda function has now been blacklisted. I'm unsure how to proceed as I am a junior and very new to all this.

Is there a way to resolve this? Can I get a new IP address? Is this going to be super costly?

Comment: Note that you appear to be violating [*"4. C. You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate."*](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) Your "online converter" may violate other terms as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339683/9793169

> I am wondering if it's possible that our because our volume is low we just always end up using the same container hence the same IP address?

Yes, that is exactly the reason.  A container is only spawned if no containers are already available.  After a few *minutes* of no further demand, excess/unneeded containers are destroyed.

> If so is there any way to prevent this?

No, this behavior is by design.

**SOLUTION:**

I logged out for 20 minutes and went back to the function and ran it again. It worked

Comment: Logging out for 20 minutes and logging back in is never a solution to a software problem. What you should be doing is implementing a retry policy on the client side so that your code self recovers. Maybe you are writing this software for yourself so it doesn't matter, but high quality software would not require the user to log out and wait 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

youtube-dl lack of delay (limit of request per time) option.

(see suggestion it the bottom of my post).

NEVER download more than one video with youtube-dl.

You can search youtube-dl author contact (e-mail etc) and write them directly, also as open issue on github page regarding it. as more request they have as fast they be pleased to fix it.
Currenty they have planty same request on this issue in gitlab but they hardly to block discussions and close tickets by this problem.
This is some sort of misbehaviour I believe.

I also found that developer suggest to use proxy instead of introducing delay option in his code - extremely funny.
OK, re to use proxy - but this actually does not solve the problem since it is lack of program design and no matter you use proxy or not YouTube limits is still here.

Please note:
This cause not only subj error but blocking your IP by YouTube.
Once you hit this situation YouTube will block your IP as a suspicious again and  again even with a small requests amount. this cause tremendous problems since IP marked as suspicious.

Without limiting request per time option (with safe value by default) I consider **youtube-dl** as a **dangerous software** should cause problems and I stopped using it until this option will be introduced.

1. RECOMENDATIONS:

Use Ctrl+S (suspend) , Ctrl+Q (resume) when youtube-dl collecting digest for many videos (when you already donloaded many videos of channel but new one still there). I suspend it for a few minutes after eatch 10.

And use **--limit-rate 150K** (or as low as it sane), this may help you to not hit the limit since whole transmission is shaped.

Comment: better solution when having a playlist is just to start from the last video so youtube-dl won't make sever request for all previously downloaded video and get 429 - Too many request. I fixed it using the flag `--playlist-start N` while N is the number of the next video on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not my solution, it took me a while to understand what he ment (reading is an art). It worked for me.
(see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220266/youtube-dl-do-not-working-http-error-429-too-many-requests-how-can-i-solve-this)
You have to use the option --cookies in combination with a current/correct cookie file.
Here the steps I followed
1. if you use Firefox, install addon cookies.txt, enable the addon
2. clear your browser cache, clear you browser cookies (privacy reasons)
3. go to google.com, and log in with your google account
4. go to youtube.com
5. click on the cookies.txt addon, and export the cookies, save it as cookies.txt (in the same directory from where you are going to run youtube-dl)
6. this worked for me ... youtube-dl --cookies cookies.txt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=....
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

use `--force-ipv4` option in command.

```
youTube-dl --force-ipv4 ...
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59628708/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score -2):

What you should do is handle that error by retrying the requests that are throttled.

Comment: This is not the answer. The request was cancelled by Youtube and their rate limit settings for the IP Lambda was using. Below, I posted the answer and solution.