# Different IP address per AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a use-case that requires my lambda to send outbound requests to a third-party (i.e. the lambda needs/has internet access). However, for each of those outbound requests I need my lambda function to have a different IP.

As an example:

```
lambda [192.168.1.2] -- outbound request --> example.com
lambda [192.168.1.3] -- outbound request --> example.com
lambda [192.168.1.4] -- outbound request --> example.com
lambda [192.168.1.5] -- outbound request --> example.com
lambda [192.168.1.6] -- outbound request --> example.com
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No. You don't have control on IP address lambda assumes when it is invoked.

Comment: What is your use-case for requiring a different IP address? Such requests are usually for web-scraping a website against their Terms of Usage. We do not condone such behaviour here. Hopefully you have another reason?

Comment: Absolutely, I understand. Crucial part of that is whether the terms exist and/or if they state that this kind of data extraction is prohibited. Regardless of the use-case I am stil interested to know ther answer :)

Comment: If they are blocking your usage based on IP address, then it is highly suggestive that they don't want you to do what you are doing. You should also be careful that such activities do not violate the [AWS Acceptable Use Policy](https://aws.amazon.com/aup/). Check to see whether the site has an official API to provide the information you seek.

Comment: I just posted the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74108003/20270660